# Laplace Distribution evaluating integrals with absolute value functions

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I found the the following question from stackexchange from two years ago:

[Laplace function and how to integrate it in order to find the cumulative distribution function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3909162/laplace-function-and-how-to-integrate-it-in-order-to-find-the-cumulative-distrib)

Here is the (correct) answer of user "Henry":

> $F(x)=\int\limits_{y=-\infty}^{x} \frac \beta 2 e^{-\beta |y|} \,dy$
>
> but for x>0 you need to deal with the change in sign of |y| to get
> $F(x)=\int\limits_{y=-\infty}^{0} \frac \beta 2 e^{\beta y}\, dy +
>  \int\limits_{y=0}^{x} \frac \beta 2 e^{-\beta y}\, dy =\frac12
>  +\left(-\frac12 e^{-\beta x} +\frac12\right)= 1 - \frac12 e^{-\beta |x|}$

The second term $\int\limits_{y=0}^{x} \frac \beta 2 e^{-\beta y}\, dy$ makes intuitively sense for me but I don't understand why he adds the first term (which results to be 1/2) since we are only considering cases where x>0. I've been googling now several hours for more intuition but I am still struggling with this part.
Can somebody intuitively explain that to me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when $x > 0$, the expression being evaluated is still $\int_{-\infty}^x f(x) dx$, i.e. we have to integrate over the entire interval $(-\infty, x)$. To do so, we can apply the identity $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^c f(x) dx + \int_c^b f(x) dx$ to split the integral into its two parts.

Then, since on the interval $(-\infty, 0)$ we have $|y| = -y$, and on the interval $(0, x)$ we have $|y| = y$ which simplifies each component.

[image]

Visually, if we're looking to find the value of the CDF $D(x)$ at the blue line, we're taking the integral to find the blue shaded area. Notice that the area to the left of the origin corresponds to the $\int_{-\infty}^0$ part, and because of the symmetry of the distribution it corresponds to an area of exactly $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you. Great explanation.